# Totally confused about app-thinning

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-thinning

From what I have been able to understand from Apple's documentation, there is a 100mb over-the-wire limit on downloadable apps from the app store.

Apple recently introduced 3x assets for iPhone6+, causing ridiculous levels of bloat in our applications.  Thus, app-thinning...  So the idea is, I add an asset catalog and put all my images in there, and then the app store will know when an iPhone 6+ user downloads the app, it will only give them the 3x and 2x versions (i'm assuming for zoomed / non-zoomed), and when an iPhone 6 user downloads the app, it will give them the 1x and 2x versions (i'm also assuming for zoomed / non-zoomed).

So the 3x users are really only saving space by not downloading the 1x size assets (which are small and insignificant).  And the 2x users are saving space by not downloading the 3x size (which is significant)...  However, my question is app-thinning is only available for iOS9..  So what does that mean?

An iPhone 6 user on iOS8 will not be able to download the app at all because they don't have app-thinning and therefore they would be downloading the entire collection of assets and it will exceed 100mb?

I am asking this question because I uploaded my cocos2d game build to iTunes Connect and it says its compressed file size is 172mb with a yellow exclamation point, so I am worried about this...  In my case, I know the problem really comes from the 3x size art.  I'm not currently using asset catalogs because cocos2d (v2.x at least) doesn't support them, and I don't want to bother adding support for that if it's pointless as I am thinking based on what I've described above...

Answer (score 0):

App slicing takes place on the App Store Servers so devices running iOS 8 or earlier are still able to download apps, which have app thinning enabled.
The [App Thinning Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html) states

> Sliced apps are supported on devices running 9.0 and later; otherwise, the store delivers universal apps to customers.

If the size of the universal app exceeds 100MB, the user has to download it over WiFi. A method to lower the initial download size are on demand resources.

Note:
As the pixel density on the iPhone 6 Plus is higher than on other models, even when non-zoomed, only the 3x images are needed so the 2x images do not need to be downloaded so the iPhone 6 Plus users do save a little bit more.